# Is there a mechanism in Python that ensures fairness in concurrency?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, round-robin

I have just tried `concurrent.futures` module to play with concurrency and found that ThreadPoolExecutor is distributing the tasks according to the availability of the thread.

**Is there any approach to distribute the tasks equally (like the round-robin technique) to ensure fairness?**

code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1z4CWPX0wAqHgPXjyolPQ9rjob2R_Ma_M?usp=sharing

```
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
    futures = {executor.submit(is_prime, number) for number in range(h_range + 1)}
```

The output of the code is given below. Here threads 0, 1, and 2 have done all the tasks. but expecting the tasks will be distributed to each of the threads equally and assign the next task according to availability to execute the program parallelly.

```
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_0
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_0
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_2
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_2
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_2
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_1
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_0
ThreadPoolExecutor-8_1
```

**Background**

[In the shared code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18VG8QMMbalGAVcQKl7rUDDZ9YWxyHfIp#scrollTo=nku9m2L-H8WS) `thread_pool_with_chunked` method has used all the threads and returned the output in 25 sec. But the first chunk has completed the task within 10 sec and it was idle the rest of the execution time. So, to make the code more efficient, the tasks should be distributed in threads equally so that no thread can be idle in the execution time. That is the goal of this question.

Comment: First, your `is_prime` function is 100% CPU-intensive calculations for which multithreading will not improve performance because of contention for the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). In this case only one thread will actually be executing at a time until its time slice is up. If `is_prime` has finished its calculation for one submitted task and it still has not completed its time slice, it will pick the next task of the input task queue. This is why you see what you see. Insert a call to `time.sleep(1)` at the start of `is_prime` to cause the thread to release the GIL and see what happens.

Comment: @Booboo I've got your point and it's valid. but let me explain the scenario where the confusion arises.

(In the shared code)[https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18VG8QMMbalGAVcQKl7rUDDZ9YWxyHfIp] `thread_pool_with_chunked` method has used all the threads and returned the output in 25 sec. But the first chunk has completed the task within 10 sec and it was idle the rest of the execution time.

So, to make the code more efficient, the tasks should be distributed in threads equally so that no thread can be idle in the execution time. That is the goal of this question.

Comment: The link you posted produce an Error 400 response.

Comment: @Booboo https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18VG8QMMbalGAVcQKl7rUDDZ9YWxyHfIp

Comment: My guess: `prime_count_in_range_with_execution_time` is doing a lot more work than `is_prime` (a single submitted task requires much more CPU time to complete). By time the first thread's time slice is up the other threads in the pool have started and because the first submitted task has not yet completed the other threads have a chance to pull a task from the task queue. **Your "unchunked" version takes much longer to execute because of the overhead of writing and reading 5_000_000 items (tasks) to the pool's task queue.**

Comment: Agreed with your last comment, I have tried a newer version in `thread_pool_with_chunked_single_instance` function where the chunks are divided to reduce the length of the executor list. But instead of distributing each chunk to different threads, in this case, I've tried to complete each of the chunks by all the worker threads at a time. Still, the execution time is 10x slower.
code: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18VG8QMMbalGAVcQKl7rUDDZ9YWxyHfIp#scrollTo=676TD3oNFyoR

Comment: In your latest code you are still submitting 5_000_000 tasks in which your worker function is passed a single number. But getting back to the title of your post, which contains the word "fairness": In none of your code examples is there anything that is "unfair". You are getting the maximum concurrency possible given that you are using multithreading for a CPU-intensive task. What difference does it make which threads in the pool are doing the actual work when only one thread can be working at at time? (more...)

Comment: If these were I/O-bound tasks that could truly execute concurrently and you discovered that only a single thread were executing all the tasks, then you should be concerned. But that is not the case here.

Comment: Another approach is being tried where the executor is initiated in every iteration. But still, the total execution time wasn't reduced.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/18VG8QMMbalGAVcQKl7rUDDZ9YWxyHfIp#scrollTo=fxtzMxAKImJZ